# Shortest way of determining a name ends with an `s`, `x` or `z`, and then use the `I18n.t` method with it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

I'm creating a Rails application where users can have a first and last name. Since I'm a perfectionist, the application may not show something like `Dennis's profile` or `Xianx's profile`, but rather `Dennis' profile` and `Xianx' profile`. I use I18n, so I wanted to ask what is the **shortest** way of implementing this? This grammar is the same for both English and Dutch, where the application will be translated to.

Oh, some important things:

- I am not afraid of using helpers and the application controller
- My language files are in Ruby, not YAML

Thanks!

Comment: I hate to be the spoilsport then. ;-) But tags should be descriptive and helpful in searches.

Comment: Damnit! I thought it was helpful for those other `perfectionists` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to be perfect in Dutch

```
 def having_s( word ) # maybe genitiv_s  is a better name
   case word[-1,1]  #  [-1] will do in ruby 1.9 
     when 's', 'x', 'z' 
       "#{word}'"
     else 
       "#{word}'s"
     end
  end

  names=%w(Alex Inez Kees Maria Bordeaux)
  names.each{|name| puts  having_s(name)}
```

The last testcase ("Bordeaux") yields a wrong result, according to [this](http://www.onzetaal.nl/advies/sainttropez.php).

Comment: eaux is always pronounced as 'o', so I can add that to the list. Also, for now it's not really a matter of life and death, as users can upload there vCard (with a small chance that It contains the phonetics if their name) and I can also ask the user if the site isn't sure :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement this with little risk of not being correct:

Instead of:

```
Person X's profile
```

Do:

```
Profile: Person X
```

There's not going to be a way to do the first for all languages/countries/cultures.  The 2nd option may not look ideal, but you won't ever present anything incorrectly.